# Customized Cross Validation Function in Combination with GridSearch

Tags: python, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I am currently teaching myself Python and Machine Learning and I am working on a project dealing with classification. I have executable code which I want to rewrite for myself and learn with it.
Now I've reached a point where I can't get ahead on my own. I use an ensemble with different classifiers like AdaBoost, CatBoost, XGBoost, etc.

The first function is a customized cross val function, which is understandable.
The second function is an extended function of the GridSearch, which I do not fully understand and now want to rewrite to a "normal GridSearch function". I would appreciate any hints and help concerning the second function

The original "customized" GridSearch called ParamSearch can be found here:
https://effectiveml.com/files/paramsearch.py

```
def crossvaltest_cat(params, X, y, n_splits=5):
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
    accuracy, score, f1 = [], [], []
    for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index, :], X.iloc[test_index, :]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        
        clf = CatBoostClassifier(**params)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        
        y_pred = np.array(clf.predict(X_test))
        tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()
        
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
        score.append(score_function(tp,fp,fn,tn))
        f1.append(f1_score(y_test, y_pred))
        
    return np.mean(score)

def cat_param_tune(params, X, y ,n_splits=5):
    ps = paramsearch(params)
    for prms in chain(ps.grid_search(['border_count']),
                      ps.grid_search(['l2_leaf_reg']),
                      ps.grid_search(['iterations','learning_rate']),
                      ps.grid_search(['depth'])):
        res = crossvaltest_cat(prms,X, y,n_splits)
        ps.register_result(res,prms)
        print(res,prms,'best:',ps.bestscore(),ps.bestparam())
        print()
    return ps.bestparam(), ps.bestscore()
```

Comment: These are implemented in `sklearn`, you may be interested in 1) seeing If it's interoperable with your models or 2) looking at the source code

Comment: I don't get what you mean with a different grid search, is it naive grid search without  cross validation?

Comment: By different grid search I mean, that I want to use the normal GridSearch in combination with the crossvaltest which is implemented in sklearn instead of "paramsearch".